# Python, Pyinstaller creating shortcuts in windows

Tags: python, tkinter, shortcut, win32com, pyinstaller

I am making a python script that creates a shortcut (`.lnk`) file, using `win32com.client` module, I am using `pyinstaller` to convert it to exe. I'm also using `Tkinter`, so I need `--tk` support in `pyinstaller`. `Pyinstaller` doesn't seem to work with `--tk` and import `win32com.client` at the same time (I have no idea why) I need this to work. Maybe there's a way to create shortcuts without `win32com.client` (I've searched a lot without success) or to make `pyinstaller` work (I foud an issue between `win32com.client` and `pyinstaller` [here](http://osdir.com/ml/python.pyinstaller/2006-02/msg00069.html)  , but the patch did't solved my problem) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, [I found a way of creating shortcuts](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/create-a-shortcut.html) using `win32com.shell` rather than `win32.client`.
This works well with `pyinstaller` and `--tk` flag set to `ON`.